# How to print list vertically using recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, reduction

I want to print this list vertically recursively:
Example:

```
print_list(['hi', [22,45], 'dog', 21])
```

Expected:

```
hi
[22, 45]
dog
21
```

Here is my code:

```
def print_list(n_list):
    if len(n_list) == 0:
            return
    else:
        half = len(n_list) // 2
        for i in range(half):
            if half == 2:
                print (n_list[i], sep = "\n")
        else:
            print (n_list[half+i])
```

Here is what I am getting:

```
hi
[22, 45]
dog
```

I am not sure why the list does not print in full. This also happens for lists with more items, only a portion shows. I know I am messing something out in the print statement but can't figure it out...

Comment: This is a homework question, isn't it?

Comment: Naansense HW, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but you are not applying reduction as your function does not call itself. This is a slightly modified version of your code that should work:

```
def print_list(n_list):
  if len(n_list) == 0:
    return
  else:
    half = (len(n_list) + 1) // 2

    # Print elements in the first half:
    for i in range(half):
      print(n_list[i])

    # Print second half using recursion:
    print_list(n_list[half:])
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
n_list = ['hi', [22,45], 'dog', 21]
print(*n_list, sep='\n')
```

gives

```
hi
[22, 45]
dog
21
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this function produce the result you want?

```py
def print_list(n_list):
    for item in n_list:
        print(item)
```

I'm not sure why exacly you only try to iterate over half the list `half = len(n_list) // 2`?

Comment: and you don't need the `str`.

Comment: it does... However I am supposed to solve it with the reduction method, that's the point.

Comment: @CasperNe it seems like your question isn't quite clear. There are items missing because you divide the range by two. What do you mean with reduction method? Your question doesn't state that anywhere.

Comment: @CasperNe For reduction you'll need a recursive function. You don't have recursion anywhere in your code.

Comment: I forgot to put it in my original post but yes, that's how I am supposed to solve this problem through reduction.

Comment: @CasperNe so edit your post to actually explain your question and limitations.